# Search ms-access database via a lookup & relationship field

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

I'm working on a project where a form will pull information from an Access database.  We have techs that are assigned to various stores, and instead of listing all of the stores and assigning a tech, I was looking to have a list of techs and assigning stores.  Right now, the database has 4 fields.

- Gate Tech - Text Field
- Expiration Date - Date Field
- Doors - Yes/No checkbox
- Stores - Lookup & Relationship field that can have multiple selections

My form has a text box, search button, and a rich text box.  If someone puts in a store number, it searches the Lookup & Relationship field and if that store is checked then it will put the tech in the rich text box.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim lstscmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Stores = @Stores", myConnection)
    lstscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stores", CInt(text1))

    dr = lstscmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(dr("Gate Tech").ToString + Environment.NewLine)
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

At `While dr.Read` I get

> Row handles must all be released before new ones can be obtained.

I would like it search the `Stores` field for any selected stores, and return the `Gate Tech` value to the rich text box.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are reusing object variables: the connection and datareader are not declared anywhere.  DBProvider objects should be created, used and disposed as needed - something appears to be still in use with that reader from the last time.

Comment: `While dr.Read` --> `While dr.Read()` according MSDN Read method requires parenthesis https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: @Plutonix I have 'Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader' under public classes and 'provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\Jm\Documents\Database15.accdb" ' Change it to your Access Database location
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString' under Form Load

Comment: Thats my point - they are form level objects you are reusing and should not be.  decalre and create them as you need them, where you need them and dispose of them.

Comment: @mcNets I just corrected that, thank you.  Unfortunately it still is giving me the same error.

Comment: Thats a non issue in VB - you can omit parens on methods with no ill effect - not a good idea, but allowed

Comment: I moved them out and into the sub but I'm still getting the same error.  If I change my "Where Stores" and to "Where ID" and search the ID field the gate tech comes up like it should.  It seems to only do it if I'm searching the stores field.

Comment: a) when more than one person comments, you have to add the @+username thing for them to be pinged.  I revisited this by accident. b) I think there is something you havent told us.  The event signature is .NET , and those are NET Provider objects.  But that error is associated with VBA/VB6 and ADO [example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257731) note the Applies To at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I found where I was going wrong and the best way to solve it.

Instead of pulling the data from the table field, I created a query in access and pointed my search to that.

```
Dim lstscmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Stores = @Stores", myConnection)
lstscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stores", CInt(text1))
```

Replace `Table1 (or your table name)` with `Query1 (or your query name)` and it should start pulling values.